# What is behind a Rindler horizon? Or is there nothing?

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, event-horizon

Most of my friends say that a Rindler horizon is an artefact of acceleration. Space continues behind it.

A few of my friends say that the Rindler horizon is an event horizon and a particle horizon. Nothing can be said to be behind it, like for any other horizon, because anybody that sees the horizon cannot observe anything behind it.

Who is right?

Comment: Your second set of friends are correct. The appearance in the rindler frame is that the observable universe contracts to a finite horizon behind you. However such a frame is not possible to reach since it requires an eternally accelerating (and accelerated) observer.

Comment: @NinadMunshi is there any problem with eternally accelerating observer? Let's say that someone standing still starts accelerating at rate of e^(-t). He will never go too fast, converging to the speed of 1 m/s at infinity, but he will be eternally accelerating to this speed, with acceleration approaching zero (but still finite and positive at any point). If all we need is eternally accelerating observer, will this one do the job?

Comment: @Kusavil the key point is the thing in parentheses at the very end. The eternally accelerating observer has also been eternally accelerated. If you were to draw worldlines in the initial rest frame of an accelerating observer that is starting to accelerate, you can reach points in your light cone "beyond" the apparent distance of the horizon.

Comment: @NinadMunshi ohh, looks like I was thinking about something slightly different, thank you for explanation!

Comment: @kusavil oh gotcha, I found some other misunderstanding because I misread your first comment. When you said accelerate to $1$, I thought you meant the speed of light. Your situation doesn't meet the requirements of a Rindler observer anyway because a Rindler observer always has the same constant acceleration relative to its instantaneous rest frame (tangent to its worldline)

Answer (score 4):

> A few of my friends say that the Rindler horizon is an event horizon

Your few friends are incorrect. An event horizon and a Rindler horizon are both Killing horizons, which is a local property. So locally they are indistinguishable. However, globally an event horizon does not "escape" meaning that it does not connect to future null infinity. Since the Rindler horizon does escape it is not an event horizon.

> Nothing can be said to be behind it, like for any other horizon, because anybody that sees the horizon cannot observe anything behind it.

This claim is equivalent to saying that nothing can be said to be in the future because nobody can observe anything in the future. In flat spacetime many null surfaces are Killing horizons, so you are always "behind" all Killing horizons that intersect with your past light cone and outside all the rest.

People making such claims are continually surprised as they go to the future, crossing multiple Killing horizons, and finding that there is indeed more than nothing where they previously thought there was nothing.

Comment: Thank you! What does "escape"/"connect to null infinity" mean exactly? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Roughly speaking, future null infinity is the set of events that are asymptotically approached by future-directed null worldlines as their affine parameter goes to infinity. Inside the horizon null worldlines intersect the singularity at a finite affine parameter.

Comment: The difficulty I have is whether there is a difference between Rindler and black hole horizons. An infalling observer also sees no black hole horizon, similar to the inertial observer in the Rindler case. So in both situations there are observers that see a horizon, and others that don't. In what sense are the two situations still different?

Comment: @Christian I already answered that. There is no difference locally. The difference is only that globally the Schwarzschild event horizon does not escape to future null infinity while the Rindler Killing horizon does.

Answer (score 3):

There can be stuff behind event horizons. After all, most of the observable universe is behind an event horizon due to the accelerating expansion.

You can make the Rindler horizon appear and disappear by changing acceleration. The only thing that changes is what particles and light can catch up with you. It is very much a personal horizon like the terrestrial horizon.

Comment: But stuff behind the event horizon is untestable? How do we know it is there?

Comment: @Christian - Do you think parts of the universe you cannot see actually disappears? Aren't you worried that I might accelerate away from you, making you disappear behind a horizon?

Comment: Well, if you accelerate away, I can still see you, I think. And I do not believe that things exist beyond the cosmological horizon... - but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The Rindler Horizon is the depicted by purple lines (Lightlike worldline [$ x = ct $] not [$x=-ct$]). This centre $O$ is the point when seen from Rindler co-ordinates would appear to be at constant displace if the person had Worldlines indicated in red( Lines of constant ($x'$)).

So at Rindler Horizon, the light pulse seem to be frozen and any observer moving with a proper acceleration will not see anything cross the horizon due to infinite time dilation.

It is a bit different from Event horizon. Due to the fact that we can't see beyond the Horizon, from our perspective we cannot tell whether there is anything behind it or not. But from the inertial frame as indicated in the diagram we can tell there are events that are possible beyond the Rindler Horizon.